# Library for displaying a map with path on it

Tags: android

I'm looking for an android library that would allow me to display a map and draw a poly line on top of that map (poly line would have geographical coordinates)

I know there is [the one from Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility), but it seams it only works with Google API, while I need it to work with PTV API. I can write wrappers if necessary as essentially I'd like to just send to the view/fragment a bitmap of a map, boundaries of it and a poly line consisting of geographical data and let it display the data correctly

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to draw a path.
here is the link for the library - https://github.com/ar-android/DrawRouteMaps
Add that library into your Android project.
Apply the following code inside onMapReady Method
Android Code:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
mMap = googleMap;

//Pass the origin coordinates(latitude,longitude)
LatLng origin = new LatLng(-7.788969, 110.338382);

//Pass the destination coordinates(latitude,longitude)
LatLng destination = new LatLng(-7.781200, 110.349709);

DrawRouteMaps.getInstance(this)
        .draw(origin, destination, mMap);
DrawMarker.getInstance(this).draw(mMap, origin, R.drawable.marker_a, "Origin Location");
DrawMarker.getInstance(this).draw(mMap, destination, R.drawable.marker_b, "Destination Location");

LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
        .include(origin)
        .include(destination).build();
Point displaySize = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, displaySize.x, 250, 30));
}
```

You can also change the route color by applying this code inside **colors.xml** :

```
" color name="colorRouteLine">YOUR COLOUR CODE "
```